# Getting primitive type from object using generic

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to store key-value pairs in a database. Value  may be one of types: `bool`, `int` , `double`, `string`, `DateTime`. In the class below the `Set<T>`-operation works, but `Get<T>` throws an `InvalidCastException`.

```
public class PersistedKeyValueStorage
{
    AppDbContext _dbContext;
    public PersistedKeyValueStorage() : this(new AppDbContext()) { }
    public PersistedKeyValueStorage(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext; 
    }

    public T Get<T>(string Key) {
        var record=_dbContext.Set<StoredKeyValueItem>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == Key);

        if (record != null) return (T)(object)(record.Value); // here is error
            return default(T);                
    }

    public void Set<T>(string Key, T Value) where T : struct            
    {
        var record = _dbContext.Set<StoredKeyValueItem>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == Key);
        if (record != null) record.Value = Value.ToString();

        else _dbContext.Set<StoredKeyValueItem>().Add(new StoredKeyValueItem { Key = Key, Value = Value.ToString() });

        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
// class usage

var skvs = new PersistedKeyValueStorage();
skvs.Set("test.int", (int)123);
skvs.Set("test.boolean", true);
skvs.Set("test.datetime", DateTime.Now);

ViewBag.testint= skvs.Get<int>("test.int");
ViewBag.testbool = skvs.Get<Boolean>("test.boolean");
ViewBag.testdate= skvs.Get<DateTime>("test.datetime");
```

Comment: I suspect it would work doing this: `var record=_dbContext.Set<StoredKeyValueItem>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == Key).Value`

Comment: And `Set<T>` doesn't work unless `Get<T>` also works. It's like saying that your encryption code is working fine, you just can't decrypt the value, this has no meaning. They have to both work or none of them work because they're a package deal. The reason I say this is because in order for `Get<T>` to work you may end up having to change `Set<T>` to not use strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing all values as strings in your store.

So when you get them back, they will be strings.

To get from `object` to `T`, then the actual object has to be either:

- a value type of type `T`
- A reference type that can be reinterpreted as `T`

An `int` is a value type, but when doing `(int)obj` you can only *unbox* the value inside, and it has to be an `int`. In your case it is a `string`. This won't work.

Instead you will have to use a conversion layer that converts to and from your storage type, `string` in this case.

For some types you can try changing your code to this:

```
return (T)Convert.ChangeType(record.Value, typeof(T));
```

But this won't handle all types that are eligible for `T`.

Comment: Convert.ChangeType  works on all types i enumerated, Thanks!